# Installing tcptraceroute on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, libpcap, tcptrace

I am trying to install tcptraceroute on my Ubuntu.  I cannot use apt-get because there is a firewall issue.  So I downloaded the package on my local and scp it over.  When I run the ./configure command, it barks at me saying

```
checking for pcap_open_live in -lpcap... no
configure: error: cannot find libpcap
```

I downloaded the following into the tcptraceroute directory:

libpcap.so.1()(64bit)

How do install libpcap?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to download the .deb-package manually? All Ubuntu packages are also available online for download, eg at http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/tcptraceroute

You can then install the downloaded package simply by typing (as root)

> dpkg -i >YourPackageName<

The important thing is that you have to resolve dependencies manually too, and install them in order (eg first libpcap, then tcptraceroute)

If you rather use a GUI, you can also simply doubleclick the XYZ.deb-file in your filebrowser, that should start ubuntus package management software and install it for you